# How to make the three images touchable

Tags: android, image, react-native, touchableopacity

Please help me make the images touchable so I can call a function onPress

```
renderSideButtons = (isGift: boolean) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ bottom: 745 }}>     
        <View style={styles.threeButtonsCustom}>
          {isGift && 
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.threeButtons}
            onPress={this.openAllergenList}>            
            <Image 
              style={[styles.threeButtons, { top: 545 }]} 
              source={require('../../assets/images/icons/gift_fbutton.png')} 
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>}
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.threeButtons}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../assets/images/icons/star_white.png')}
              style={[styles.threeButtons, { top: 235 }]}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.threeButtons}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../assets/images/icons/share_white.png')}
              style={[styles.threeButtons, { top: 195 }]}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>      
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Here is styles.threeButtons style

```
threeButtons: {
    position: 'absolute', 
    right: 175, 
    width: 50, 
    resizeMode: 'contain', 
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
  },
```

and the additional styling

```
threeButtonsCustom:{ 
flex: 1, 
flexDirection: 'row-reverse', 
position: 'absolute', 
marginTop: '20%', 
zIndex:1 }
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrmO3.jpg for example the gift image

Comment: add " zIndex: 1" in the threeButtons style

Comment: You want to tap three images at once?

Comment: I have zIndex: 1 in upper View {styles.threeButtonsCustom} which i should also paste sorry, 
threeButtonsCustom:{
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '20%',
    zIndex:1
  },  
it haven't helped.

Comment: I want to tap them separately but now they are not even clickable

Comment: what is threeButtonsCustom style, please share.

Comment: possible the same reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257992/7913142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I'm noticing in your code.

1. You are opening a conditional section in your code, but don't seem to close it. Look at `{isGift &&` and show me where you are closing your curly brackets.
2. You only have an `onPress` defined for your topmost `TouchableOpacity`. You currently cant click on any of the other buttons because nothing will happen when you do.

Fix both of these issues, and then let me know where you are.

Also, for future reference, any styling that you are applying to components you have questions about is good to give in your initial question, and when supplying styling people ask for in comments, should go in an edit to your question so future visitors can easily see it.

Comment: thank you i just rewrite the whole function, i have used flex and now it works